# Failed the last task of Openstack Autopilot via Landscape

Tags: openstack-autopilot

Lab:

All environment Lab has been realised using only Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

1 VM for MAAS + conjure-up (memory: 8GB, CPU: 1, HDD: 500GB);

1 VM for JUJU (memory: 8GB, CPU: 1, HDD: 500GB);

1 VM for LANDSCAPE (memory: 8GB, CPU: 1, HDD: 500GB);

5 VM for OPENSTACK (memory: 16GB, CPU: 1, HDD: 500GBx2);

After to have deployed JUJU, and LANDSCAPE via conjure-up, the last step is to deploy Openstack via Landscape. The initial situation is showed above:

[image]

LANDSCAPE has all the requests completed

[image]

select the public network

[image]

and complete the task selected the modules

[image]

then let's start with its own installation

[image]

All machines are deployed

[image]

the progress goes head

[image]

then about 50%, received that error:

[image]

any suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that. The issue was on the network configuration of VMware ESX, corrected that the deploy of Openstack has completed all tasks.

[image]

after that

[image]